# How to append image to dynamically created table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I trying for a long time to append a image to td whose class is add_status.The class is defined dynamically 
here is the code i tried.

```
$('.index > tbody:last').append
    ('<tr><td class=col-checkbox><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids" value="'+response[i].PROSPECT_NO+'"></input>'+
    '</td><td class="show_hide"><a href="#">'+response[i].PROSPECT_NO+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].COMPANY_NAME+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].PROSPECT_SOURCE+
    '</td><td>'+days+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].PROSPECT_TYPE+
    '</td><td class="add_status" style="text-align:center"></td><td><a href="">edit</a></td>'+
    '</td><td><input type="hidden" name="client_id" class="client_id" value='+response[i].CLIENT_ID+
    '></input></td><td><input type="hidden" name="client_id" class="client_id" value='+response[i].JOB_ID+
    '></input></td></tr>');
    }
```

To append my loading image

```
$('<img>', {
src: 'css/Images/ajax-loader.gif',
class: 'img_status',
    }).appendTo("tbody td");
```

I am trying to append loading image because my response will be slower.
thanks.

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: I cant append image to td

Answer (score 3):

try append using class name like below

```
$('.index > tbody:last').append
    ('<tr><td class=col-checkbox><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids" value="'+response[i].PROSPECT_NO+'"></input>'+
    '</td><td class="show_hide"><a href="#">'+response[i].PROSPECT_NO+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].COMPANY_NAME+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].PROSPECT_SOURCE+
    '</td><td>'+days+
    '</td><td>'+response[i].PROSPECT_TYPE+
    '</td><td class="add_status" style="text-align:center"></td><td><a href="">edit</a></td>'+
    '</td><td><input type="hidden" name="client_id" class="client_id" value='+response[i].CLIENT_ID+
    '></input></td><td><input type="hidden" name="client_id" class="client_id" value='+response[i].JOB_ID+
    '></input></td></tr>');
$('<img>', {
    src: 'css/Images/ajax-loader.gif',
    class: 'img_status',
        }).appendTo(".add_status");
        }
```

Comment: actually this is beacuse you have appended your td first class add_status and then after you will get the exact class where you want to append your image.@ling.s

Comment: if you got your exact answer then dont forget to mark as answer.@user3064914

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('<img>', {src: 'css/Images/ajax-loader.gif', class: 'img_status'}).appendTo("tbody td.add_status");
```

Comment: you sure image path is correct 'css/Images/ajax-loader.gif'

Comment: $("td.add_status").html('<img src="/css/Images/ajax-loader.gif" />');

Comment: its correct if a append to thead td i can see my image. The problem is i cant append image to dynamically created tbody tr

Comment: when you need to append ajax-loader.gif image? after click on some element?

Comment: append image is inside my load status function.